# I can scroll down, but there is no content

Tags: html, css

So my problem is that you can scroll down even if there is no content down there. Like it's just blank. Here's my code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Mr.Shisha | Homepage</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div align="center">
    <h1 style="font-size: 112px;">Mr. Shisha</h1>
      </div>
      <nav>
    <div style="position: relative; left: 650px;"class="dropdown">
<a href="index.html"><button class="dropbtn">Shishas</button></a>
  <div style="position relative; left: -40px;"class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
    <a href="#">Link 5</a>
    <a href="#">Link 6</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="position: relative; left: 700px;"class="dropdown">
<a href="index.html"><button class="dropbtn">Tabak</button></a>
<div style="position relative; right: -40px;"class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>
<a href="#">Link 4</a>
<a href="#">Link 5</a>
<a href="#">Link 6</a>
</div>
</div>
<div style="position: relative; left: 750px;"class="dropdown">
<a href="index.html"><button class="dropbtn">Kohle</button></a>
<div style="position relative; left: -40px;"class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>
<a href="#">Link 4</a>
<a href="#">Link 5</a>
<a href="#">Link 6</a>
</div>
</div>
<div style="position: relative; left: 800px;"class="dropdown">
<a href="index.html"><button class="dropbtn">Bongs</button></a>
<div style="position relative; left: -40px;"class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>
<a href="#">Link 4</a>
<a href="#">Link 5</a>
<a href="#">Link 6</a>
</div>
</div>
<div style="position: relative; left: 850px;"class="dropdown">
<a href="index.html"><button class="dropbtn">Zubehör</button></a>
<div style="position relative; left: -40px;"class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>
<a href="#">Link 4</a>
<a href="#">Link 5</a>
<a href="#">Link 6</a>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
<div style="position: relative; left: 1815px;"class="div1"></div>
<div class="round" style="; position: relative; bottom: 340px; left: 1825px;">
<a href="https://facebook.com/mr.shisha11" target="_blank"><img src="p/f.png" width="80px"></a></div>
<a style="position: relative;left: 1825px; bottom: 310px;"href = "mailto: mr.s@yahoo.com"><img src="p/e.png" width="80px"></a>
<div style="position: relative; bottom: 270px; left: 1825px;">
<a href="https://www.google.com/maps?cid=9446396123572628496" target="_blank"><img src="p/s.png" width="80px"></a></div>
<img class="img1" src="p/wi.gif">
<div style="position: relative; bottom: 1250px; left: 20px;"class="div2"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
```

I'm not the best at HTML/CSS I know that. I found nothing about that problem online. Is it possible that when you use too many div's or something like that, that happens? Or do i have a problem in my CSS and my HTML is alright?
Edit: Heres the netlify link: https://jolly-roentgen-d0fc0f.netlify.com/

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Using your browser's developer console, it should not be too hard to find any interesting things

Comment: Some elements are positioned off-screen at certain window sizes (e.g. `left: 850px;` and `left: 1825px;`); I can scroll right and see some of them. Instead of pixel positioning, a layout that more closely follows [normal document flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Normal_Flow) will likely be more [flexible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26244153/924299) -- using percentage position, [floats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Floats), [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox), etc.

Comment: How is the layout intended to look?

Comment: What do you mean? How the website should look? https://jolly-roentgen-d0fc0f.netlify.com/

Comment: Yes, I mean what do you want the page to look like. [Here's an example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Structuring_a_page_of_content#Example). You might also find this helpful: [Introduction to CSS layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Introduction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem at least on one place

```
<div style="position: relative; bottom: 1250px; left: 20px;"class="div2"></div>
```

Remove this bottom: 1250px and all other bottoms that you have and I guess you will not have scroll issue any more

Comment: But i need it for the box that is there. When i remove that the box is at the bottom.

Comment: And i can go to the right too, but there is no content

Comment: You can put the box at the bottom with position: fixed, and not like this. It would be helpful if you could put codesendbox or codepen or something like that in the question so that somebody could help you with your code.

Comment: https://jolly-roentgen-d0fc0f.netlify.com/ you can see everything there